# publish .net mvc to a remote windows server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, iis-7

I am facing a problem publishing an mvc webapi to a remote server. Currently i have deployed the website to the server and am I able to run the site in the windows server browser as a localhost however when i try to access it over the internet thought the public ip address i get a 404 error of file not found.

The port is open. i'm using iis 7.0 and windows server 2008.

I have checked all the bindings to the port! I tried to check if mvc is installed and all I read says that mvc comes already with iis 7 and webplatform installer says that .net 4.5.1 is installed

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just some simple ideas of how to resolve it. Hope they are usefull.
a) Check the app pool of the application. Set it to the correct .NET framework if required.
b) A very simple test I perform to see if its the app or the url. 
- Stop the app. 
- Place your app in a folder temporarily. 
- Place a simple index.html HTML file where your app should be. 
- Browse to it and see if 404 shows.
c) if its a new box and not set correctly you might need to set up IIS for Application Development. Check this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763178%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) with regards to setting it up. Expand the tree to make sure you select what you need.

Comment: I checked and the asp.net is installed in the server. I also tried to do a simple html file and placed on the folder as you said and I still got a 404 error of file not found.

Comment: So it is easy to deduce that this isn't a publishing problem, nor a mvc problem. It is an IIS issue. do you get the default IIS splash screen when u navigate to the box? Have you checked the firewall rules? Are there any proxies you need to look at and configure?

Comment: No proxy. Firewall rule por the app specific port in windows server is created and I do get the iis splash screen if I navigate to the root